# what is the general solution of this differential equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y^4 y' + y + x^2 + 1  = 0 $$

this looks very similar to a Bernoulli differential equation, I believe it can be solved by that way , but is there an alternative way to do that?

Comment: This is not a Bernoulli type ODE.

Comment: Does the differential equation look more familiar in radial coordinates by any chance?

Comment: Was somebody able to solve this question?? It isn't a Bernoulli type ODE, neither is it exact{nor reducible to exact}